# SQLite DB in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Can you please tell me how to create SQLite DB in iPhone and to perform CRUD operations from objective c program to databases. How to do it programmatically??

I know to create DB and table through command line, but how to do it programmatically??

Help me..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Add the libsqlite3.dyllib library to your project.** Right-click on the Frameworks group, select Add->Existing Frameworks... and scroll down to select and add libsqlite3.dyllib.
2. **#import**  in your source file.
3. **Open or create a database file** with the path in an NSString `file` using this code:

   ```
   int error = sqlite3_open ([file cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &database);
   if (error != SQLITE_OK) {
       NSLog (@"Error result from sqlite3_open(): %d", error);
       sqlite3_close (database);
   }
   ```
4. **Execute commands** in an NSString  `aQuery` with this code:

   ```
   char *errorMessage = nil;
   int error = sqlite3_exec (database, [aQuery cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], nil, nil, &errorMessage);
   if (error != SQLITE_OK)
       NSLog (@"Error result from sqlite3_exec(): %d: %s", error, errorMessage);
   if (errorMessage != nil)
       sqlite3_free(errorMessage);
   ```
5. **Close the database connection** with sqlite3_close (database);

For more info on the C interface, see http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html.

Answer (score 1):

By far the best example (if you can find it) is Apple's sample code called SQLiteBooks. It came with versions of XCode prior to Core data. I have a copy lying around, so if you can't find it send me a message and we can arrange something.

That will give you a very good start.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to user CoreData. Start googling about to use that or look at some sample projects. Will take probably 2-3 days to learn Core Data but it does CRUD a lot better.